# Is 1111::/64 a valid IPv6 address?

Tags: router

As per the rules for shortening IPV6 address given in https://networklessons.com/ipv6/shortening-ipv6-addresses, this IPV6 address is invalid.
But still this address gets accepted when configuring a Network element. Why?

Comment: While that _is_ a valid format for IPv6 addressing, that particular IPv6 network is in a RESERVED range. See the IANA _[Internet Protocol Version 6 Address Space](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml)_ page. Your example, `1111::/64` falls in the `1000::/4` Reserved by IETF range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is a valid IPv6 address. I fail to see why you think it is not based on that website. As is stated: "An entire string of zeros can be removed, you can only do this once", which is correct.

So `1111::/64` expands to `1111:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/64`.

Comment: When entire string of zeros are removed, `1111:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/64` will become `1111:/64`, right? Not `1111::/64`. Why there is an extra colon?

Comment: The extra colon is to indicate a sequence of removed zeros.

Comment: Original: `2041:0000:140F:0000:0000:0000:875B:131B`
Short: `2041:0000:140F::875B:131B`. In this case, no extra colon is added for the string of zeros. So, why an extra colon is added for `1111:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/64`? Is this any special rule for string of zeros coming in the end of address?

Comment: You should read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952 paragraph 2.2: *A special syntax is available to compress the zeros.  The use of  "::" indicates one or more groups of 16 bits of zeros.*